# Libgdx Draw Texture constantly

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When my if-statement is true , I want to draw a Texture.

But the Texture is displayed for a second and directly disposes.

I wanted to ask if there is a way to stop the disposing and display the Texture even after the condition is fulfilled.

my render method:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(BackgroundImage, 0,0, BackgroundImage.getWidth(), BackgroundImage.getHeight());
    batch.end();

    // Kamera aktualisiert ihre Matrizen
    camera.update();

    // Dem SpriteBatch mitteilen , dass es das
    // Koordinatedsystem , welches von der Kamera erstellt wurde, benutzen soll
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
        batch.draw(TropfenTexture, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
    }
    bmf.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    bmf.draw(batch, ScoreString, 10, 790);
    batch.end();

    GameSpeedup();

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
        raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (raindrop.y < 0)
            iter.remove();
        if (raindrop.overlaps(BoundsBottom)) {
            //dropSound.play();
            //game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game));
            //Gdx.input.vibrate(200);
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(PfützeTexture, 0, 0);
            batch.end();
            }
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            Vector3 tmp = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(tmp);
            if (raindrop.contains(tmp.x, tmp.y)) {
                CurrentScore++;
                ScoreString = "" + CurrentScore;
                if (dropSound.isPlaying())
                dropSound.stop();
                dropSound.play();
                iter.remove();
                if (raindrop.contains(tmp.x, tmp.y) && raindrop.overlaps(BoundsBottom)) {
                    CurrentScore++;
                    ScoreString = "" + CurrentScore;
                    dropSound.pause();
                    dropSound.play();
                    iter.remove();
                }
                }
            }
        }

        if (CurrentScore > Highscore){
            Highscore = CurrentScore;
            prefs.putInteger("highscore", Highscore);
            prefs.flush();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: clarified my question and added more code

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: "when my if-statement is true , I want to draw a Texture...I wanted to ask if there is a way to draw the texture continuously" You can't have both. Either you draw the texture on a certain condition or you draw it continuously.

Comment: Create another list of objects that track splash positions. Draw those in a loop the same way you draw raindrops. Add to the splashes list when raindrop collisions are found.

Answer (score 0):

In case i understand your question correctly you shouldnt be rendering an object by checking collisions. Instead render from arrays of your game entities.

1. Check collisions and remove add entities as need. in your case: remove raindrop, add splash.
2. render objects
3. update object positions

   `if (raindrop.overlaps(BoundsBottom)) {
      waterRectangles.add(new WaterObject());
      //maybe remove raindrop?
   }
   batch.start();
   for(Rectangle waterObject: waterRectangles{
       batch.draw(WaterTexture,waterObject.x,waterObject.y);
   }
   //same for raindrops
   batch.end();
   //update positions`

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: I think this is a good answer. I was curious about the order you selected. We've been separating render into two subphases. In the first subphase we perform any changes to entities required (adding, updating position, removing, etc.) and in the second, rendering. The three steps you outlined above, the position updates are after the render, I'm curious what the reasoning for that separation is?